# Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Given a vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^ {m\times 1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Given a vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^ {m\times 1}$. 
Suppose you know

I. Vectors $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ solve the linear system  $Ax=0$

II. Vectors $x^*,y^* \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ solve the linear system $Ax=b$.

Which of the following is not a solution for the linear system $Ax=b$?

A. $x^*+z_1$

B. $y^*+z_2$

C. $x^*+y^*$

D. $3z_1+x^*-4z_2$

E. $2x^*-y^*$

$\mathbb{R}$-stands for real numbers.

The correct Answer is C but I don't understand why.

Comment: Using Mathjax can make this question much more readable, and you'll get more responses. http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Two comments: 1) linearity, 2) any solution plus a homogeneous solution is again a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Apply $A$ to each answer. For example

a) $A(x^*+z_1) = Ax^* +Az_1 = b+0  = b$

b) $A(y^*+z_2) = Ay^* +Az_2 = b+0  = b$

Answer (score 0):

$A(x^*+y^*)=Ax^*+Ay^*=b+b\ne b$.